# Coded UI Test - Windows - Universal Apps

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to automated testing of windows apps using coded-ui-test project using vs2013 ultimate edition.

I can see those templates for C# desktop applications under test category and for phone application under windows phone category.

I cannot see such template for Windows Universal Apps.

How to automate universal apps?

If I choose the coded ui template available under category Store Apps -> Coded UI Test Project (Windows)

[image: Project Template]

After project creation, recorder gives me a message "recording action steps is not supported for windows store apps"

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a CodedUI Test project for UWP.  Since you're coding UI tests, you're test project should be targeting a specific device platform. There's CodedUI templates for Windows, and also Windows Phone.  I would make two different CodeUI tests (one for Phone, one for Desktop), to make sure everything is working on either platform.

For testing common functionality, you can use unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has not yet released support for recording step definitions for mobile or universal Windows apps. The recorder is there mainly to observe UI elements and to auto-generate code and assertions on elements that have been identified with automation ID's or point references which most of us wish to avoid. This is something I am currently dealing with an I'll update this question if and when I find solutions unless someone else beats me to it, which would be welcomed.