# Windows 10 (UWP) Coded UI

Tags: visual-studio, win-universal-app, coded-ui-tests

There is no Coded UI project in Visual Studio 2015 for UWP and I can't find any documentation anywhere saying there is a plan to bring support.

Does anyone know if there is planned support it or have some alternative UI testing framework to work with Windows Universal?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872022/coded-ui-test-windows-universal-apps ?

Comment: That question doesn't answer this,  but does match my premise and the information I have found so far. I am focusing on unit tests but am hoping for codedUI since UWP is supposed to be the MS next big thing

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use this Coded UI Test Project (Universal Windows) which is under

> File->New->Project->Templates->Windows->Universal-->*Coded UI Test Project (Universal Windows)*

for Coded UI project in Visual Studio 2015 for UWP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an important information for other to come is. That it’s not possible to create such projects in the community version of visual studio. You need at least the enterprise version as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx#VerifyingCodeUsingCUITCreate).

Comment: This was with enterprise Visual Studio. Coded UI projects were available for old architectures, but not UWP.

Answer (score 0):

An update for anyone arriving at this question is that Microsoft are deprecating support for Coded UI testing after the Visual Studio 2019 release...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code?view=vs-2017

> Coded UI Test for automated UI-driven functional testing is deprecated. Visual Studio 2019 is the last version where Coded UI Test will be available. We recommend using [Selenium](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/) for testing web apps and [Appium with WinAppDriver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver) for testing desktop and UWP apps.

So, the suggested answer by Microsoft for automating UWP UI testing is to adopt [Appium with WinAppDriver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver).