# How to do Coded UI Test Automation in a UWP App having only a WebView

Tags: webview, win-universal-app, coded-ui-tests

I have made a **UWP Application** that contains **only a WebView**. When the App is launched the WebView is given the URL to the Azure Remote App login page where I can login using my Azure AD Credentials and use an App (e.g. Excel) after login. Now the problem is how do I automate all this using Coded UI? I have the following two projects in Visual Studio that I used.

[image]

Now the problems are:

1) **Record and Playback options are not supported for UWP** in both the projects.

2) If I use Coded UI Test Project (Universal Windows), **It cannot detect the WebView or control/elements inside the WebView** (so this is of no use for me).

3) If I use Coded UI Test Project (Universal Windows - Phone), It is able to detect the webview and the elements inside it like the email and password fields and the sign in button, but in the code **I don't have anything like XamlWebView** which I can use and then use the SearchProperty to find the email field and use it (So I am half way there).

The only two links that I found relevant are:

[Windows 10 (UWP) Coded UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025122/windows-10-uwp-coded-ui)

[Coded UI Test - Windows - Universal Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872022/coded-ui-test-windows-universal-apps)

But they don't offer much help.

I also went through the **WinAppDriver** (saw a video on Channel9 of //build 2016 where Gopinath and Yusuf explained about WinAppDriver) thing but was not able to figure out whether it can be used in my Scenario and how.

I hope I expressed my Question clearly. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I also got this link-  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/29ccc541-cccd-4848-aba2-a8c4676404fb/automation-of-windows-store-app-with-webview-in-windows-10?forum=vstest                                             But the options suggested didn't help in my situation.